# What is the number of interior faces adjacent to an interior vertex in a triangulation in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, triangulation, finite-element-method

Let $\Omega$ be a polygonal domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Assume $\Omega$ is partitioned into tetrahedra using the most common admissible [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(geometry)),
that is, roughly speaking, two adjacent tetrahedra meet vertex-to-vertex, or edge-to-edge,  or face-to-face.

The question is:

> Suppose $z$ is an interior vertex in $\Omega$ 
>   and there are $m$ tetrahedra having $z$ as a vertex. 
>   Can we determine the number of faces adjacent to $z$ ? If so, what is it (expressed using $m$) ?

Comment: There are $3m/2$ adjacent faces.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @san How to show that $m$ must be an even number?

Comment: Else you would have a face that is adjacent to only one tetrahedra and then $z$ wouldn't be an interior point.

Comment: Consider the 3D equivalent of the [edge-flipping algorithm in 2D Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping). Does that not allow you to change from, say, $m=8$ to $m=9$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3m/2$ adjacent faces, and $m$ must be an even number. Else you would have a face that is adjacent to only one tetrahedra and then $z$ wouldn't be an interior point.